# Why my PyQt5 Webview Code is not working?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qwebengineview

This is my code. Why its not working?
Where is my problem?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication



class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(1280, 960)
        self.widget = QWebEngineView()
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1270, 920))
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.widget.load(QUrl("google.com"))
        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take your time to follow the [tour] and read [ask] good questions, and consider that "why it's not working" is a very broad question. *What* is not working? Is the window shown? Is the web widget displayed? Or is the problem that it doesn't show the webpage? Please, try to make yourself more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has 2 problems:

1. The QWebEngineView is not a child of the window so it will not be displayed. Change to `self.widget = QWebEngineView(Form)`
2. `QUrl("google.com")` is not a valid url so you have 2 options, change to:

   - `QUrl("https://google.com")` OR
   - `QUrl.fromUserInput("google.com")`